# GET errors in ruby on rails. Controllers and actions. CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controllers

I'm working through the "Ruby on rails essential 3 training" on lynda.com. I'm at the point of creating forms and implementing CRUD. So far whenever I try to have rails initiate an action it can never find the definition.

To solve this problem I define the action within the controller and then create a GET within my routes.rb file.  My instructor doesn't have to do this and his server starts just fine.  I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong because my routes.rb file has far to many GET commands.

Please look at the following folders and let me know if you have an idea of why I have to make a GET every time I try a new action.  I heard that when creating a Model there is supposed to be a GET created at the same time but that isn't happening and I'm not sure if I'm understanding that correctly.  My subjects controller:

```
    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
    list 
    render('list')
end

# def index
#   show
#   render('show')
# end

def list 
    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
end 

def show 
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @subject = Subject.new

end

def create 

end
```

end

My new.html.erb file:

```
    <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-         link') %>

    <div class="subject new">
        <h2>Create Subject</h2>

        <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

            <table summary="Subject form fields">
                <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My config/routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root :to=>"demo#index"
      get 'demo/index'
      get 'demo/hello'
      get 'demo/other_hello'
      get 'subjects/list'
      get 'subjects/show'
      get 'subjects/new'
      get 'subjects/create'
```

Now having an issue with the Create portion of Crud when trying to create a test subject.  Here is my SubjectsController.rb

```
    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
    list 
    render('list')
end

# def index
#   show
#   render('show')
# end

def list 
    @subject = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
end 

def show 
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @subject = Subject.new
end

def create 
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

    if @subject.save 

    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else 

    render('new')
    end

end

    end
```

Comment: please post the error that you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do not need to specify `GET` for `CRUD` actions. You can use **Rails Resource Routing**. For example, your `subjects` controller actions can be called in **routes.rb** like so:

```
resources: subjects
```

This will automatically route all the generic CRUD actions, and look for them in your controller. You can see whether rails "picked up" your routing by typing `rake routes` in the command line. You can also limit the number of actions you want by passing `resources: subjects, only:[:destroy]`. This tells Rails to only use the `subjects#destroy` action. There is more to it. I suggest reading through [this RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your config/routes.rb should look like:

```
root 'subjects#index'
resources :subjects
get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and resources this really helps out a lot and makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Okay so now I am stuck on the create part of Crud.  I've been able to fix my routing so that my server works but when I try to create a test subject I get the Forbidden Attributes error.  I will post my SubjectsController.rb file in my original question if you could take a look at it.  I've followed the instructor but I'm guessing this is again a routing issue or lack of defining 'create' or 'params'

Comment: If you're getting a forbidden attributes error it's because Rails uses 'strong parameters'. At the bottom of your controller there should be a method called 'subject_params' - you need to make sure all the parameters that you're passing in through the create method are listed in that method.

Comment: Okay thank you for this. I discovered that my routes folder is all messed up so now I'm back to the list and show parts of the crud but once that is organized I'm going to make the create method work. How long have you been using rails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72889/discussion-between-ohhendrie-and-sam-gruse).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you have to create routes by yourself. They are not created with a model. Also, they are rather related to the controller than to the model.

I recommend to have a look at the official Rails routing guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Usually something like *subjects/create* is not a GET but a POST route. Your instructor might also have used a `resources :subjects` route instead of multiple GET/POST/etc. routes.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variant of @OhHendrie's answer using only the resources dsl

```
root 'subjects#index'
resources :subjects do
  get 'list', on: :collection 
end
```